# Table locked by background worker in PostgreSQL RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, blocking, pgadmin, logical-replication

We have one RDS PostgreSQL running. I run pg_locks to check the locks on objects -
There is this one table which is always locked( RowExclusiveLock ) by Superuser and when I try to get the details of that session from pg_Stat_Activity, it shows a Background worker and looks like it's not even doing anything, This table is part of replication and this lock causes replication session to get blocked.
Any clue?

[image]

Comment: Check what extensions you have installed. It might be caused by one of them.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for the response. I did check. 
There are these extensions installed -
"plpgsql"
"unaccent"
"uuid-ossp"
"plperl"
"pg_stat_statements"
"dblink"
"postgis"
"fuzzystrmatch"
"postgis_tiger_geocoder"
"postgis_topology"
There was pg_repack,pgstatuple and pgaudit as well which I removed after your comment. I still see that background worker blocking the same table and it's indexes.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I tried terminating that session but that respawn immediately.
This table is a part of replication. data is getting inserted through logical replication and this table is getting replicated from this instance to SQL server through attunity.

Comment: You'll have to identity the backend process. For that, look at `pg_stat_activity` as superuser.